# Special characters from .js file not appearing correctly initially

Tags: javascript, tomcat, gradle, intellij-idea, webpack

I deployed a .war file through IntelliJ Idea on a Tomcat server.
I noticed a character "ä" was not properly displayed while at other places the same character was displayed correctly. I found out that only the special characters that I hard-coded in my .js files were affected.
I tried to set all my .js files to UTF-8 in IntelliJ, I also changed all standard encoding settings to UTF-8 but the error didn't go away.
All my js files are mapped into one index.js  file using webpack, but how exactly I don't know because this is a project initially set up by someone else.

I recently made a new interesting observation:
When I first open up a browser (tested with Firefox and Chrome) it's displayed incorrectly:
[image: Wrong display]
On regular reload (`F5`) nothing changes, but when reloading with `CTRL + F5` it's suddenly correct:
[image: Correct display]
This really confused me...does anyone have an idea what might be going on here?
I used to have the same problems with my Java files, but after changing the encoding in my gradle build file that worked.
Ultimately my question is:
**What do you think should I change in order for the special characters to always be displayed correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This really confused me...does anyone have an idea what might be going on here?

Caching. Ctrl+F5 tells the browser to reload the resource even if it has it cached. F5 will reuse the resource from cache if it's in cache.

> What do you think should I change in order for the special characters to always be displayed correctly?

You may have already done it given the F5/Ctrl+F5 thing above.

Basically, ensure that:

1. The files (.js, .html, etc.) are stored in the correct encoding and, when viewed with that encoding, show the characters correctly. Strongly recommend using the same encoding for each type of file, although theoretically it's possible to use UTF-8 for JavaScript files and (say) Windows-1252 for HTML files. But that's just asking for complexity and hassle.
2. Ensure that every step in the pipeline correctly identifies the encoding being used for the files. That means (for instance) that Tomcat needs to include the header `Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8` or similar for your .js files. (`text/javascript; charset=utf-8` will also work, but is obsolete.) For HTML files, though, [the W3C recommends](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) including the `meta` header and *omitting* the `charset` from `Content-Type`.
3. Ensure that your HTML files identify the encoding in a `meta` tag near the top of `head` (within the first 1024 bytes) as well: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` The W3C [provide several reasons](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) *(same link as the bullet above)* for doing this, such as saving the file locally and opening it (thus not having an HTTP header), making it clear to human and machine readers, etc.

Comment: But what confuses me about the caching: after it worked and I close the browser, open it again and open the site: it's wrong again. Shouldn't the correct js version be in cache after getting it with CTRL-F5 before?

Comment: @Cold_Class: Yes, it should. No idea what that could be I'm afraid. You'll need to check encoding on each step in the process...

Comment: It turned out, the login screen didn't have the meta-tag, so the .js was loaded incorrectly. The html after the login had the right tag, that's why other things were correctly displayed except for the initially loaded .js file. On reloading it, it was correct because the meta tag was there this time.

Comment: @Cold_Class: Ah, nice one tracking it down! I've also updated the answer with a W3C link about the `meta` tag, from which I learned something. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I add a similar problem after a tomcat update on a Windows server: the javascripts  content corrupted characters at the browser side.
The http headers were corrects so I investigated a bit further.

On the server, the javascript files were saved in utf-8 without BOM.

With Wireshark, I saw that the character 'é' (C3-A9 in the file UTF-8 encoded ) was transmitted as (C3-83-C2-A9). It means that **Tomcat was reading an ANSI file** and gently converted it to UTF8!

So I just added the BOM to the saved the files and it fixed the bug. (REM: it is easy to add the BOM with notepad++).

But I didn't want to update all the server files, I wanted tomcat to read UTF-8 correctly.

The easy fix is to define the file encoding in the **tomcat web.xml** like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!------------------- add the settings here ------------->
    <init-param>    
        <param-name>fileEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <!------------------- end of the added settings ------------->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```